# No logro poner la aplicación por defecto - Android

Tags: android

Estoy tratando de poner mi APK por defecto, al inicio del programa verifico si esta es la por defecto:

```
//Comprobando si es el SMS por defecto
boolean habilitar = shp.getBoolean("pref_enable_sms_por_defecto", true);
if (habilitar) {
    Intent intentsms = new Intent(this, ComposeSmsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intentsms);
}

con el siguiente cuadro:
```

[image: Cambio AP SMS]

e inmediatamente voy a:

```
public class ComposeSmsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private SharedPreferences shp;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    shp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
final String myPackageName = getPackageName();
if (!Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this).equals(myPackageName)) {
    // App is not default.
    // Show the "not currently set as the default SMS app" interface
    AlertDialog.Builder sms_default = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    sms_default.setTitle("Cambio AP SMS");
    sms_default.setMessage("Usar Nautilus SMS por defecto?");
    sms_default.setPositiveButton("Sí", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
            intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, myPackageName);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    sms_default.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shp.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("pref_enable_sms_por_defecto", false);
            editor.apply();
            finish();
            }
        });
        sms_default.show();
    }else {
        MsgToats("Nautilus SMS es la AP por defecto");
    }
}
private void MsgToats(String msg) {
    Toast sms_dest =
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    sms_dest.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.RIGHT, 50, 200);
    sms_dest.show();
}
}
```

Aqui debiera aparecer la que esta por Defecto y mi APK para seleccionar cual deseo que sea mi aplicacion por defecto:

[image: Seleccion de APK por defecto]

Nada solo me sale la APK que se encuentra por defecto, y la mia no aparece por ninguna parte. Qué estoy haciendo mal???

Answer (score 0):

Puede que la razón por la que no aparezca en la lista es que le faltan algunas etiquetas al **Manifest.xml** de tu aplicación. Android verifica estas etiquetas para determinar que aplicaciones se pueden usar por defecto en determinados servicios.

Esta respuesta que te estoy dando es una versión resumida de la respuesta aceptada de esta pregunta (en inglés) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30127564/how-do-i-set-my-app-as-the-default-sms-app, que se parece mucho a la tuya.

Más información acá [Getting Your SMS Apps Ready for KitKat](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html) . Aunque aquí se hable específicamente de KitKat, no creo que haya cambiado mucho el cómo opera android actualmente.